# How to set hash in Facebook iframe app.?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe, facebook-iframe

I've created iframe application for vk.com. Navigation uses browser hash inside my app. And now I want to port it to Facebook, but I got a problem. I can't find any possibility to set browser hash from my iframe application. Unlike Facebook, vk.com has a support of this feature (using their global object, I don't know details about implementation..).

The essence of my question: can I set browser hash from my iframe application in Facebook?
I understand that it's impossible using native javascript, because parent window and my iframe have a different domain name. How can I decide this problem?

I really hope that someone khows the answer, because I don't like an idea to refactor my application's code for Facebook.. :)

P.S. Sorry for my English))

Comment: You can only use the hash on the address of the document inside iframe itself – if that’s enough for your navigation to work inside of the iframe, take it. But that won’t let you _link_ to a special part of your app from the outside of course – that is not possible by using just a hash.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you cant :( But I think you could replace your hashtags with get-params in your url.

```
https://domain.com/yourapp#startpage
```

to

```
https://domain.com/yourapp?startpage=1
```

In your application you should be able to read the url, I think